# How can i cahnge picture when i click on pagination item in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, pagination

Im new to javascript programming and i have one issue that i would like to clarify.
My goal is to change picture when i click on one pagination item.

```
<ul class="pagination pagination-lg">
              <li>
                <a href="#">Prev</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="JavaScript:void(0)" id="prva" onclick="changePhoto('placeholder', 'images\webPages\1.jpg')">1</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="JavaScript:void(0)" id="druga" onclick="changePhoto('placeholder', 'images\webPages\2.jpg')">2</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="JavaScript:void(0)" id="treca" onclick="changePhoto('placeholder', 'images\webPages\3.jpg')">3</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">4</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">5</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Next</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
```

and my script is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function changePhoto(id, newPic){
    document.getElementById(id).src = newPic;
</script>
```

the id of current image is placeholder, but it doesnt do anything when i click on 1,2 or 3... 
i give you image of how it looks:
[the image of website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrVZv.jpg)
can anybody help me with this code?
Tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of issues.
 1. You are not escaping your slashes
 2. You didn't close the changePhoto function with a closing }

**Example Change Of onclick function to escape slashes**

```
onclick="changePhoto('placeholder', 'images/\webPages/\2.jpg')"
```

Comment: thank you for your fast reply, but this didnt solve my problem. i agree, it was stupid of me i didnt close function with a }, i edited my code to escape my slashes, but still it doesnt do what i want it to do :/ 
help me to tame this little beast :D